# Tagify tags overflow input element instead of wrapping

Tags: tags, tagify

I am using tagifyjs to allow user to select multiple items and be displayed in a typical tag format. When multiple items are selected from the list, the tags overflow the input element. I want the height of input element to increase as more elements are added. Here is a picture of what happens:

[image]

Here is a picture of what I really want to happen.

[image]